# Does Android compiler honor -Wall?

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker

I'm trying to build a shared object with the following recipe in our [`Android.mk`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-android). The shared object is based on a C++ library.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cryptopp_shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix $(CRYPTOPP_PATH),$(CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS := -Wall
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL -Wl,--as-needed

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The library builds mostly OK. Some options are *not* being honored, like `-Wall`. Other options like `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` are being honored.

The docs for [Android.mk is here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk), but it does not discuss removing or filtering options.

Why is Android's build system not honoring all of our flags?

---

Here is the build command we used. I build from the library's root directory:

```
ndk-build V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$PWD" \
    NDK_APPLICATION_MK="$PWD/Application.mk"
```

The odd thing is, all of our source files are C++ and none of the source files were built with `-Wall`. However, we import Android's cpufeatures library, it is one C source file, and it was built with `-Wall`:

```
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -MMD -MP -
MF /home/cryptopp/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cpufeatures/cpu-features.o.d -gcc-t
oolchain /opt/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/lin
ux-x86_64 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wn
o-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-
prefixes -fno-integrated-as -g -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi18 -march=arm
v7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -DNDEBUG  -I/opt/android-ndk
-r16b/sources/android/cpufeatures   -DANDROID -Wall -Wextra -Werror -D__ANDROID_
API__=18 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  --sysroot /opt/andr
oid-ndk-r16b/sysroot -isystem /opt/android-ndk-r16b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linu
x-androideabi -c  /opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features
.c -o /home/cryptopp/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cpufeatures/cpu-features.o
```

Given I used `LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS := -Wall` I would think the opposite would happen - all C++ source files would build with `-Wall`, and the one C file would build without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mere typo, you need `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`, only one `_` there.

As for `cpu-features.c`, it receives `-Wall` because  `$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/android/cpufeatures/Android.mk` requires this in `LOCAL_CFLAGS`.

Comment: Thank your very much. So I am clear... Should we set `-Wall` in both `LOCAL_CFLAGS` and `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`? Or just `LOCAL_CFLAGS`? Or just `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: `LOCAL_CFLAGS` works for both C and C++. If you need some special settings, such as `-std=c99`, you can use `LOCAL_CONLYFLAGS`.