# Insert the text in the end of single line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am using the shell function to get some command output.
in this case, I use 2 functions to run 2 commands and put in the 2 files

```
Currenly output
A.txt
TAG1 1002110 96465223
TAG2 2123054 85656562
TAG3 9525468 86125866

B.txt
TAG1 10.11.12 11.11.13
TAG2 12.11.12 12.00.13
TAG3 13.11.12 13.00.13
```

how do I put the command B output at the end of A file like that?

```
A.txt
TAG1 1002110 96465223 10.11.12 11.11.13
TAG2 2123054 85656562 12.11.12 12.00.13
TAG3 9525468 86125866 13.11.12 13.00.13
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Take a look at the `join` command.

Comment: thanks... got some error for that when i put the join A.txt B.txt when run the .sh " is not sorted:"

Comment: Do both files have exactly the same tags in the same order?

Comment: What are your 2 commands? Perhaps we can do that in one go.

Comment: thanks  it is mq command dis q(*) and dis qs(*)...

Comment: Looks like we got @jww-ed so I'm upvoting all the answers as usual to compensate.

Comment: @EdMorton Looks like somebody has moved on to a new strategy: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43837637#43837637

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm not sure what I'm looking at on that page. Is that jww removing his comments or someone else removing them or something else? btw have you seen the tool someone wrote to find jww comments to help identify the source of bulk downvoting - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/890812/have-i-been-jwwed. I wonder if the 2 are related.

Comment: @EdMorton I was mostly pointing out that instead of leaving a comment, he now marks questions he doesn't like as "close please" in the SOCVR chat room.

Comment: I had no idea such a thing existed. He was whining at me this morning that some of his posts had been downvoted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026973/does-android-compiler-honor-wall#comment91004744_52026973) and threatening retaliation as he thought it was me who did it. It wasn't so, of course, I promptly DID downvote him in response :-). Sounds like he's taking this whole site just a wee bit too personally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste A.txt B.txt | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6}'
```

Comment: thanks, work with paste $a.txt $b.txt > $c.txt

Answer (score 2):

With join and bash's Command Substitution:

```
join <(sort A.txt) <(sort B.txt)
```

Output:

```
TAG1 1002110 96465223 10.11.12 11.11.13
TAG2 2123054 85656562 12.11.12 12.00.13
TAG3 9525468 86125866 13.11.12 13.00.13
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){val=$1;$1="";sub(/^ +/,"");print a[val],$0}' A.txt  B.txt
```

Comment: thanks, if i only want to output A.txt and after i run the funcB can add the output at the end of A.txt?